# Taking photos with a phonegap/cordova application and convert into base64image before upload to them to the server

Tags: javascript, java, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

i am capturing  capture image from camera using cordova plugin after i am getting image file location which is stored in catch
file patch is

```
    file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mm/catche/54251.jpg
```

i want to convert into base64 image file.how can i get base64 string .

```
<button class="hide_file" type="button" onclick="capturePhotoWithFile();"></button>
    function capturePhotoWithFile() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 30, 
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.Camera
    });
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
$('#Image1').attr("src",imageURI);// getting file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mm/catche/54251.jpg 

  }
```

i want to convert Image URI into base64 image file.how can i get base64 string .

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation of.
[Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameragetpicturesuccesscallback-errorcallback-options)

Based on the destinationType of the camera configuration returns the respective image format.

Henceforth getting the base64 image destinationType should be DATA_URL and on success call back.

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

}

Comment: i am getting data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mm/catche/54251.jpg file not proper image base61 string

Comment: Few questions from me have you changed the DestinationType of your camera options to DATA_URL.